# Basic C++ inheritance challenged by my compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void ok( float k ){ std::cout<< "ok..." << k; }
    virtual float ok(){ std::cout<< "ok..."; return 42.0f; }
};

class Test : public Base
{
public:
    void ok( float k ) { std::cout<< "OK! " << k; }
    //float ok() { std::cout << "OK!"; return 42; }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    float k= test.ok(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation under GCC 4.4 :

```
hello_world.cpp: In function `int main()`:
hello_world.cpp:28: erreur: no matching function for call to `Test::ok()`
hello_world.cpp:19: note: candidats sont: virtual void Test::ok(float)
```

I don't understand why `float ok()` defined in Base isn't accessible to Test user even if it does publicly inherit from it. I've tried using a pointer to the base class and it does compile. Uncommenting the Test implementation of `float ok()` works too.

Is it a bug compiler? I'm suspecting a problem related to name masking but I'm not sure at all.

Comment: Unrelated, but still a problem: your `Base::ok()` returns a `float`, but has no return statement.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I checked that it don't change the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called *name hiding*, any derived class field hides all overloaded fields of the same name in all base classes. To make the method available in `Test`, add a `using` directive, i.e.

```
using Base::ok;
```

somewhere in the scope of `Test`. See [this for more information](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/overload_member_fn_base_derived.htm).

Comment: Wow! Now I understand that I never did use twice the same name for virtual members and so never got to this problem before... Still constantly learning when using C++ O__O

Comment: @Klaim: the main issue is about the fragile base, you would not want to break the derived classes code when introducing a new member in the base class.

Answer (score 6):

No. It's not a bug. It's just that derived `class Test` is hiding the `Base::ok()` method due to same name. Just do following and it should work:

```
class Test : public Base
{
public:
  using B::ok; // no need to declare parameters; it will allow all ok()
...
};
```